# how to sort datagridview ignoring blank rows

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, gridview-sorting

I am using a DataGridView control in WinForms to populate data. While sorting it, it considers blank rows as well.
I want to move those blank lines to the bottom of the grid.
Whatever the sort criteria is.

Please help to do this?

This is on the similar lines like [DataGridView sorting with nulls in DateTime column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870752/datagridview-sorting-with-nulls-in-datetime-column)

But the problem is if DataGridView is DataBound or its VirtualMode property is set to true.
SortCompare event doesn't work.

Comment: Why do you have 'blank rows' ?

Comment: User can add and edit rows. So the feature is like this.

Comment: That fails to answer my question. Please define 'blank row' exactly.

Comment: Let's say there is a grid control which is having columns as, EmployeeName, Address, contact no. It has got 5 records in it. Now the feature allows user to add blank rows to enter new employee records and save them back to DB. Now, if grid is sorted it considers those blank rows as well.

Comment: OK, I think I understand. They are bound to an object, but the object contains no values?

Comment: From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95scxcdy.aspx): "To customize sorting for columns bound to an external data source, you must use the sorting operations provided by the data source. In virtual mode, you must provide your own sorting operations for unbound columns." Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699642/how-to-sort-databound-datagridview-column), I hope it can help in your situation.

Comment: try DataGridView1.Columns[i].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic; it may solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this on your data access

if the sort is ASCENDING - ORDER BY (CASE WHEN EmployeeName IS NULL then 'Z' ELSE EmployeeName END)

if the sort is DESCENDING - ORDER BY (CASE WHEN EmployeeName IS NULL then 'A' ELSE EmployeeName END)