# Sorting DataGridView with null datetimes

Tags: c#, sorting, datetime, datagridview, null

I have a datagridview with a column of DateTime values and some of them are null. There isn't a problem until I try to sort by that column. I've implemented the SortCompare code as found here

[DataGridView sorting with nulls in DateTime column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870752/datagridview-sorting-with-nulls-in-datetime-column)

but the debugger is still throwing exceptions and pointing to my  `Application.Run(new MainForm());`
line, saying

```
Object must be of type DateTime.
```

I've got a `try-catch` in my SortCompare event handler, and I'm able to step through all the code successfully. It's only when the event handler returns that the exception is thrown.

How can I prevent this exception?

CODE:

Open up a new c# windows forms project in Visual Studio and throw a datagridview on the form with a `Full` dockstyle. In `Form1.cs` replace the `public Form1()` method with the following code:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Create datatable and add a datetime column
        DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
        DataColumn dColumn = new DataColumn("DateTimes", typeof(DateTime));
        dTable.Columns.Add(dColumn);

        //Add rows
        dTable.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now);
        dTable.Rows.Add(DBNull.Value);

        //Create a datagridview column and add it to the datagridview
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dgvColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        dgvColumn.Name = dColumn.ColumnName;
        dgvColumn.ValueType = dColumn.DataType;
        this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgvColumn);


        //Add rows to the datagridview based on datatable data.
        foreach (DataRow dRow in dTable.Rows)
        {
            DataGridViewRow dgvRow = new DataGridViewRow();
            dgvRow.CreateCells(this.dataGridView1);
            dgvRow.SetValues(dRow.ItemArray);
            this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dgvRow);
        }

        //Hook up sortcompare event handler
        this.dataGridView1.SortCompare += new DataGridViewSortCompareEventHandler(dataGridView1_SortCompare);

        //Style datagridview
        this.dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
    }

    private void dataGridView1_SortCompare(object sender, DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (DBNull.Value.Equals(e.CellValue1) || DBNull.Value.Equals(e.CellValue2))
            {
                if (DBNull.Value.Equals(e.CellValue1) || e.CellValue1.Equals(null))
                {
                    e.SortResult = 1;
                }
                else if (DBNull.Value.Equals(e.CellValue2) || e.CellValue2.Equals(null))
                {
                    e.SortResult = -1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                e.SortResult = (e.CellValue1 as IComparable).CompareTo(e.CellValue2 as IComparable);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Then run the program and try to sort the column to throw the exception.

Comment: I've updated my question with representative code. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing e.Handled = true; Set it to true will fix your issue.

```
 private void dataGridView1_SortCompare(object sender, DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (DBNull.Value.Equals(e.CellValue1) || DBNull.Value.Equals(e.CellValue2))
            {
                if (DBNull.Value.Equals(e.CellValue1) || e.CellValue1.Equals(null))
                {
                    e.SortResult = 1;
                }
                else if (DBNull.Value.Equals(e.CellValue2) || e.CellValue2.Equals(null))
                {
                    e.SortResult = -1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                e.SortResult = (e.CellValue1 as IComparable).CompareTo(e.CellValue2 as IComparable);
            }
e.Handled = true
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Freaking A! That `e.Handled` got me the other day with cell painting too XD. Thanks!